# Can't retrive data from webpage for onchange fields in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, xml-rpc

I have used xml-rpc in my Odoo ERP so whenever some user inputs data in external website that will come to my ERP. Everything working fine i.e. getting data which user inputs from website like personal details, But the problem is i've some onchange selection fields in custom model.for that data is not getting updated over here. Got my point?? I would like to know how to resolve this issue. At least i need to know someone's approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Sorry i dont have codes i got codes of myside only like python file with onchange functions.. i am on implementing that issue. Did you got my problem, didn't you??

Comment: Requirement is not clear. Try to share some code. From where you are trying to send data to ERP. Share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Chandu,

Well you can call on_change method on through xml-rpc which will give you desire data and you can pass those data back to the server to store correct values.

Bests